# Debugging a Bluetooth crashing problem on my Android tablet

Tags: bluetooth, tablet, crash-reports

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite 2022 and I use it with Rouvy to do indoor bike rides. Rouvy connects to the bike and to my heart rate monitor using Bluetooth.

Every 30 minutes or so, the tablet loses bluetooth connectivity to all devices. When I switch apps and view settings I can see that Bluetooth is greyed out as though it has crashed. A few seconds later Bluetooth becomes available again. I assume the app restarts.

I have enabled Bluetooth snooping and downloaded 3 bug reports from the tablet. They all show the same thing in the HCI trace in Wireshark

Output from btsnoop_hci.log.last as viewed in Wireshark
[image]
. The output shows "Event Code: Hardware Error (0x10)"

If this is a hardware issue I will take the tablet back to Samsung but is there a possibility that something else is happening? I have a full bug report from the tablet but it's 15MB in size. Any pointers to debug this would be much appreciated.

Things I have tried:

- Close down all background apps
- Network reset on the tablet
- Reboot tablet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As the Bluetooth core specification states, the event parameter ´Hardware_Code´ 0x0f is implementation-specific, which means that only the manufacturer of the hardware knows what is behind this code. In any case, this is a Samsung Service issue.